# How can i replace a number with a corresponding number in java

Tags: java, function

I have to write a java application that reads from the random number generator 5 numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive. Pass the numbers (one at a time) to a function that will replace each number with the corresponding number in the table below. Finally, write the new encrypted number.

```
Digit in   Digit out
0            3
1            9
2            4
3            1
4            7
5            6
6            8
7            2
8            0
9            5
```

Example: if the numbers entered are:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

The output will be:

```
9 4 1 7 6
```

What i have so far:

`

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class JAVAhw10

{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a, b, c, d, e;
    a = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
    b = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
    c = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
    d = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
    e = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);

    int DigitIn[] = new int[5];
    int table[] = new int[10];

    //filling in the arrays
    DigitIn[0]=a;
    DigitIn[1]=b;
    DigitIn[2]=c;
    DigitIn[3]=d;
    DigitIn[4]=e;

    System.out.println("This program ecnrypts 5 random numbers");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(DigitIn));

    func = encrypt(DigitIn, table);
    System.out.println(func);

    int[] table = {3,9,4,1,7,6,8,2,0,5};
   }

   public int encrypt(int){
    return table[int];
   }
}
```

`

Comment: you want us to code for you?

Comment: Cool. But you should use an IDE or a text editor to do it. Pasting the assignment here won't magically make the code to appear.

Comment: no Sarthak i will post my own code its just the function or method that i am seeking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. represent your table with an array or hashtable. If the Digit ins are dense an array is ok, Otherwise use a hash table (key is Digit in and value is the corresponding Digit out).
2. Send a one number at a time and get the corresponding Digit out value from the array or hashtable.
3. Combine the Digit outs and create the whole encrypted output.

An example:

```
import java.util.*;

class JAVAhw10 {
    private static final int[] table = {3,9,4,1,7,6,8,2,0,5};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a, b, c, d, e;
        a = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
        b = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
        c = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
        d = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);
        e = (int)((Math.random()*100) % (9) + 0);

        int DigitIn[] = new int[5];
        int table[] = new int[10];

        //filling in the arrays
        DigitIn[0]=a;
        DigitIn[1]=b;
        DigitIn[2]=c;
        DigitIn[3]=d;
        DigitIn[4]=e;

        System.out.println("This program ecnrypts 5 random numbers");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(DigitIn));

        int[] output = encrypt(DigitIn);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));

    }

    public static int[] encrypt(int[] input){
       int[] output = new int[input.length];
       for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
           output[i] = table[input[i]];
       }
       return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the "digit in" are random and i cant write 50 if statements to check them and then give out the proper equivalent.

Comment: That's why you have to represent the table as an array. A key of the array is a "digit in" and the corresponding value is the encrypted value ("digit out") of that.

Comment: I dont know about hashtables but i'm using arrays. Can you tell me how to check the random numbers and assign to them the corresponding digit.

Comment: public static in encrypt(int what?)

Comment: I provided the code. check if it works.. @user3857450

Answer (score 0):

You've got keys Form 0 to 9. Usw an array of length 10 for the values. For less special cases you can usw maps.